# SQL join query with a criteria from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hello i have the following problem. I am using a script written by my tutor.

Question:
Write a query to display the last name, job title, department number and department name for all employees who work in Toronto.

I am using the following query:

```
select last_name,department_id, department_name, job_title
from employees
join departments using (department_id)
join jobs using (job_id);
```

The only table I have which contains the city 'Toronto' is *locations*. The table *employees* doesn't have any links to the *locations* table.
For information, the *departments* table has a link to both locations and employees.

Can you please help me in trying to filter on anyone who works in Toronto?

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: If there is no location information in either of the tables and no locations in your ER model then it doesn't make sense to get all employees from Toronto location.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Answer (score 0):

Simple inner joins will constrain by the department's location of Toronto.

```
select  emp.last_name,
        emp.department_id, 
        dep.department_name, 
        job.job_title
    from employees emp
    join departments dep on
        dep.department_id = emp.department_id
    join locations loc on
        loc.location_id = dep.location_id
        and loc.city = 'Toronto'
    join jobs job on
        job.job_id = employees.job_id
```